# Compare Pictures has different sizes in selenium by openCV

Tags: java, selenium, opencv, selenium-webdriver, graphics2d

I am trying to include image validation in my test project, so I can validate on some ares of the website as image like teaser, footer..etc

I take a screenshot by selenium and save it as PNG file in the first time, then in every test case I will take a new screenshot and compare both of then by ShutterBug library and print the different.

The main issue that when I take a screenshot each browser has a different size and When I resize it by Graphics2D it will not be the same. I tried also with openCV but it doesn't work. because the anti-aliasing.

```
private static BufferedImage resize(BufferedImage img, int height, int width, int imageType) throws IOException {
    Image tmp = img.getScaledInstance(width, -1, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
    BufferedImage resized = new BufferedImage(width, height, imageType);
    Graphics2D g2d = resized.createGraphics();
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_DITHERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_DITHER_ENABLE);
    g2d.drawImage(tmp, 0, 0, null);
    g2d.dispose();
    return resized;
}
```

`private Mat resize(BufferedImage image, int height, int width){

    Size size = new Size(width, height);
    Mat img = Imgcodecs.imdecode(new MatOfByte(bufferedImageToByteArray(image)), Imgcodecs.IMREAD_COLOR);
    Mat resized=new Mat(size,CvType.CV_64FC4);
    Imgproc.resize(img, resized, size,INTER_AREA);
    
    return resized;
}`

Answer (score 0):

I have tried all these options but at the end i am now using
https://github.com/newsuk/AyeSpy

Aye Spy is a high performance visual regression tool to catch UI regressions.

It's very simple and manageable.

You just need to setup selenium grid and run the json file.

It will compare perfectly and give you the comparison result like

[image]

You can try it one time.Hope it will help you to generate comparison result for testing

Comment: I want to add in the test cases as there is some area in the website I want to verify on it otherwise all data it is not the same every time. that's why I am going to this approach.

Answer (score 0):

There are several open source solutions for comparing screenshots in the UI automation testing, which just does the same things as you are working on. I suggest you can try [Micoo](https://github.com/Mikuu/Micoo) which is a visual testing service, self-hosted and open source. When you get used to Micoo, you will find it's quite easy to do visual testing with it, of course, compare with different size of images is not a problem at all.